# My hashed IPV4 was published by an administrator on an anonymous imageboard (EU country)

Tags: gdpr

some days ago it on an anonymous imageboard it was opened by an administrator a thread with a .png showing all my posts on that website, and each posts had my hashed ipv4 attached to it.
Since i discovered that decrypting hash ipv4 is a walk in the park (less than 30 seconds on a normal consumer computer according to this research: https://dl.gi.de/handle/20.500.12116/16294 )
i'm here to ask you if i can start a legal cause against the admin of the website. I live in an European Union state so i should follow GDPR laws right?
The thread of which i speak it was also filled with threats and similar things, over 400 replies in total.

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the hashing algorithm. There are around 4 billion valid IP addresses (the exact calculation is complicated by special purpose ranges like 192.168.0.0/16), so the way you de-anonymise an IP address is to just search for an IP address that gives the same hash. But that requires 1: you know the exact hash algorithm and 2: it is fast enough to make the search feasible. Merely repeating the hash 1,000,000 times would make the same search take over a year.

Comment: You realise that every single website you visit knows your IP address?

Comment: yes but not every site publish my hashed IP and all my posts in the homepage just to receive insults and threats

Comment: Even though you might be in the EU, that website is likely not controlled from the EU. Then, it would only be subject to the GDPR if it offers services in the EU. Merely being accessible from the EU does not count, according to the EDPB guidance on territorial scope.

Comment: *For reassurance*: Although IP addresses are considered in scope for GDPR as personally identifiable information, it doesn't necessarily mean that they can used to do that by 'Hacker Joe' to identify a person that accessed a website. For most private citizens (those not owning a domain) it would most likely only lead back to the knowledge of which ISP that address originated from. Only then if you had further inside information from the ISP could it be traced back to a customer. Even then there would be no guarantee which person at the customers address was the person who accessed the site.

Comment: Exception to above: If you have a static public IP address that has been registered with your name and address by your ISP (which would be quite uncommon for an ISP to do that nowadays).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you have a GDPR issue, it should be reported to your local [Data Protection](https://edpb.europa.eu/about-edpb/board/members_en) authority.

However, an attacker would have to: transcribe the hash from the image; attempt to reverse the hash (unless you have actually done that yourself, you are only guessing that the hash might be easily reversible). Having done that they have an IP address, which although PII, won't be readily traceable to an individual. Then when they have done all that, they know the name of someone who posted something on a bulletin board.

So, although there maybe a GDPR issue there, it's probably too trivial for anyone to worry about.

Comment: ok, thank you :)